# HTML MouseOver and MouseOut Error

Tags: html, mouseover, mouseout

```
<tr>
<td> <span id="dummy" onclick="playSound(this,'vowels/ear.mp3');">
<img src="pics/ie.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='pics/dipthongs/ear.jpg';this.width=200;this.height=250" onmouseout="this.src='pics/ie.jpg';this.width=100;this.height=150"/>
</span> </td>
```

My problem is that the images get so big when i load the page. I have to hover to all the images before it returns to the size i declare for them. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the image to fix the width and height parameters.

```
<img src="/image.png" class="image1" />
```

Now CSS using min-width/height and max-width/height:

```
.image1 {
max-width: 500px;
max-height:500px;
min-width: 120px;
min-height: 120px;
 }
```

Create Functions

```
function mouseEffect(ele,image,className){
 ele.src=image;
 ele.className= className;
 }
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwtjt/

Comment: While, in general, that is good advice … it doesn't remotely address the question.

Comment: It could have clearly addressed it ;) I'll update my answer so it better stated.

Comment: @Quentin I updated my answer with addressing the image issue as I overlooked the rest of what OP was asking :) I figured that I saw all that inline functions and fixed that for the OP.

Comment: @EasyBB I tried the code above but still the image needs to be hover before it returns to the original size.

Comment: @user2217076 could you provide an example either through jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net as it shouldn't be doing this unless you either have an inline width and height set __or__ your have a class of `img {}` set with width property overriding the above.

Comment: @EasyBB the example you've given above is almost the same! the code I used is here. http://jsfiddle.net/beybeesheen/Pwqv3/

Comment: @user2217076 what I was getting at is do this http://jsfiddle.net/n624T/2/ this is how you should set up your HTML, and the functions. Don't use your inline functions like you were doing.

Answer (score -2):

Don't set the width in HTML itself. Use CSS to set the width. Dont set the height it will be properly scaled.

HTML

```
<img class="styleImage" src="x.jpg">
```

CSS

```
img.styleImage {width:75%; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
```

Comment: That won't make them load any faster.

Comment: Also adding img in front of the class is not needed, as the class is respectively going for images itself. So `.styleImage` would work alone, only span and div td tr and so forth should go in front and I barely do that unless it is spans and divs (since I HATE tables) `span.class` and `div.class`